# Number of odd and even permutations in a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a permutation group $S_n$ (with $n\geq 3$) which is not contained in $A_n$. Then as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626115) the number of odd and even permutations of $H$ are equal. Does that mean order of such a subgroup is always even?

In other words, what can we say about the number of odd permutations in an odd-ordered subgroup?

-- M

Comment: I’ve added a much simpler proof to the linked question.

Comment: @ThePhoenix My main question is about the odd-ordered subgroup. If I were to discard all possibilities, then such a subgroup is contained in $A_n$; hence, there is no permutation of odd order.