# Finite group with conjugacy class of order 2 has nontrivial normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with a conjugacy class of order 2. How do I go about showing that $G$ has a nontrivial normal (proper) subgroup?

Let $a$ be in the conjugacy class of order 2. [Then](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Size_of_Conjugacy_Class_is_Index_of_Normalizer) $2 = [G:N(a)]$, so $G$ has even order. Can I use that somehow?

Comment: You are done here: [since the two cosets of $N(a)$ form a group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal), $N(a)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: In fact, if $[G:N(a)]=2$ for some $a\in G$, then the right coset of $N(a)$ in the group has 2 distinct elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Can you prove that a subgroup of index $\,2\,$ in *any* group is *always* normal ?