# Group Theory : How is N Normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

G is a group and N a subgroup of G, and if index of N in G is 2, then N is Normal. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Any attempts of yours?

Comment: this question is a duplicate to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420583/normal-subgroups-and-factor-groups

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searched for quite a while but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $N$ such that $[G:N]=2$. Thus $N$ has two left cosets (and two right cosets) in $G$. If $g \in N$, then $gN = N = Ng$. If $g \notin N$, then $gN=G∖N$ as there are only two cosets and the cosets partition $G$.

For the same reason, $g \notin N \implies Ng = G∖N$.

That is, $gN=Ng$. Thus $N$ is normal in $G$.