# Let G be a group H be a subgroup of G which has exactly two distinct cosets.Let C={H'⊂G :H'=gHg^-1 for some g∈G} How many elements Of C have?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ which has exactly two distinct cosets. Let
$$C=\left\{H'⊂G :H'=gHg^{-1} \text{ for some } g∈G\right\}$$

How many elements does $C$ have?

Comment: You've been here 16 months and posted 29 previous questions. You should know how to post a much higher quality question.

Comment: Any subgroup of index 2 is normal, hence the answer is one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgroup of index 2 is Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal)

Answer (score 1):

$[G:H]=2$ so $H$ is normal in $G$ (see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420583/328173), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84632/328173)).

Therefore, it has exactly one conjugate, namely itself.