# Show $H$ is normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

$G$ has order $14$ and is not abelian. By Cauchy's theorem we know that it has an element $x$ of order $2$ and an element $y$ of order $7$.

I need to show that $H=\langle y\rangle $ is a normal subgroup in $G$. This is what I have done but I am not sure whether it is the correct approach:

$|H| = 7$, then number of Sylow $7$-subgroups $n_7 \equiv 1$ ($\text{mod } 7 = 1,8,... )$

but $n_7|2 \Rightarrow n_7=1 \Rightarrow$ number of Sylow $7$-subgroups $n_7= 1$

Thus there is an unique 7-subgroup and thus is normal.

Comment: Yes, it is correct approach.

Comment: Your proof is correct, I edited some sloppy use of notation. And, you really do not need Sylow theory to crack this problem. See @abdcef (what a name!).

Comment: I only wanted to be taken seriously with that name :( :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a general fact that if $H$ is a subgroup of  $G$, for finite groups with $2|H|=|G|$. Then $H$ is normal in $G$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420583/normal-subgroups-and-factor-groups) for a simple proof.

Comment: He asked: is my approach right?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I overlooked the question.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 : This is discussed recently [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27591/answering-is-my-approach-correct-with-a-different-proof). In particular take a look at Kevin's answer.