# The alternating group is a normal subgroup of the symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

For an exercise, I need to prove that the alternating group $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$.

As clue they say we can use a group homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn} : S_n \to \{-1,1\}$. I really don't see how i can use this.... can somebody help?

Comment: Does $\ker(sgn) = A_n$ help you?

Comment: yeah, it would but why is ker(sgn)=$A_n$?

Comment: Because every element of $A_n$ is mapped to $1$ and every other element in $S_n\setminus A_n$ to $-1$. Note that $1$ is group-unity of $(\{\pm 1\},\cdot)$.

Comment: oke thnx alot guys, i get it know i think.

Comment: Final hint: $\ker(\psi)$ for any group-homomorphism $\psi: G \to H$ between groups $G$ and $H$ is always a normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$1$.Note that kernal of sign homomorphism is precisely $A_n$ and kernal of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup.

$2$. Recall that every [Subgroup of index 2 is Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal])  and note that $[S_n:A_n]=2$

Comment: oke thnx, then i can prove it!

Comment: do you also know how i can use the given group homomorphism to prove the same?

Comment: Hint:kernal of given map is $A_n$

Answer (score 2):

Add another method to prove in addition to Arpit's answer: conjugation preserves cycle type; so $s a s^{-1} \in A_n$