# Show that $A_n$ is the kernel of a group homomorphism of $S_n \rightarrow \{−1,1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I know that the kernel is always normal but how to prove or show that $A_n$ is the kernel?

Comment: Think of the definition of $A_n$, and think of some "parity" getting involved. Of course, proving the well-definition and homomorphism is the important part, the kernel comes easily.

Comment: $\ker(sgn)=A_n$ has been proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182673/the-alternating-group-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-the-symmetric-group), see Moritz comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try building an explicit homomorphism

$$\phi : S_n \longrightarrow \{-1, 1\} $$

Let us show that $\phi(\pi_i) = sgn(\pi_i)$ is an homomorphism as asked.

Remember that any permutation $\pi_i$ can be decomposed in a number of transpositions. Although this decomposition is **not** unique, it can be shown that if some permutation $\pi_a$ has a decomposition with an *even* amount of transpositions, then all decompositions of $\pi_a$ must use an *even* number of transpositions and $\pi_a$ is said to be **even**. Analogously, if a permutation $\pi_b$ has a decomposition with an *odd* number of transpositions, then all decompositions of $\pi_b$ have an *odd* number of transpositions and $\pi_b$ is said to be **odd**.

When then define $sgn(\pi_i)$ as $1$ if $\pi_i$ is even and $-1$ if $\pi_i$ is odd.

I leave it to you as an exercise to show that $sgn(\pi_i \circ \pi_j) = sgn(\pi_i)\times sgn(\pi_j)$

Now all you have to do is show that this homomorphism has $A_n$ as kernel.

Comment: i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: @Manson no answer should more explicitly point you in the right direction

Comment: Do we only have to consider the one from above that is either odd or even

Comment: @Manson I am sorry, I didn't understand your comment.