# Defining a homomorphism from S_n to Z_2 and showing that A_n is its kernel.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I do not know to to explicitly state the homomorphism. (Revision Question).

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2004855/329832

Comment: i still cant get it.

Comment: Do you know the notion sign or signature of a permutation? If yes, use it. If no, look it up.

Comment: Can anyone please explain to me how to show that the kernel is An. I feel stuck