# Finding a normal and not normal subgroup of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> I'm being asked to find 2 subgroups of $S_3$, one of which is normal and one that isn't normal. I guess, to find the non normal subgroup is easier.

I would do this by trial and error, but since the group is $S_3$ and easily visualizable, I guess that there should be a geometrical property that makes it easy to find a normal subgroup. Any of you guys know one?
Or should I try this by brute force?

Comment: The/a normal one is the alternating group $A_3$, I guess. I think this is the only normal subgroup other than {$e$}. Now you can look at a small mount of possibilities.

Comment: For relatively small symmetric groups it's convenient to find an explicit form of their subgroups. For example, $S_{3}$ has 4 subgroups up to an isomorphism: trivail group, $S_{2}$, $A_{3}$, $S_{3}$ by itself. Then, it's straightforward to check, whether the group is normal or not.

Comment: $S_3$ has only four proper nonidentity subgroups. One is normal and three are not.  Trial and error really isn't bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT:
Keep in mind that $|S_3|=6$,  so if you have any subgroup of order 3, it has index 2 and is therefore normal.  Can you find a subgroup of order 3?

To find a nonnormal subgroup, you will need a different divisor of 6 that is not trivial,  and the only choice there is $2$, so you are looking for a 2 element subgroup.  Can you find that?

Comment: I was initially confused as to why index 2 implies it is normal. For anyone else, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal) might help.

Answer (score 7):

$S_3 =\{1 , (12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$,then $A_3 =\{1 , (123),(132)\}$ is normal subgroup of $S_3$ and $\{1 , (12)\} ,\{1,(13)\} ,\{1,(23)\} $ are  non normal subgroups of $S_3.$

Comment: Hi why is {1,(12)},{1,(13)},{1,(23)} not Normal? I am new to Group theory so I am struggling a bit.

Comment: @DominicJoseph they are not normal because they are not closed under conjugation. For example, $(123)(12)(123)^{-1}=(23)$

Answer (score 3):

$S_3$ is small enough that one can solve this by brute force, comparing left and right cosets of *every* subgroup. My suggestion: calculate *all* the left and right cosets of $H_1 = \{e, (1\ 2)\}$ and $H_2 = \{e, (1\ 2\ 3),(1\ 3\ 2)\}$, first.

Answer (score 0):

$H_1=\{e,(1 2)\}$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_3$. However, $H_2=\{e,(1 2 3),(1 3 2)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3$.

Comment: I do not see what this adds to the other answers from 6 years ago. In particular, it is covered by the answer of [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1361425/10513). (You would be better focusing on newer questions.)

Comment: ı studied this topic today,so I just  want to add this examples. thanks for advice :) I'm new using this website.(my english is bad ,sorry)

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: do not rewrite already existing answers. Similarly, when asking about homework, show your own work, instead of trying to make others do it for you...

Comment: thank you for advice @PrudiiArca:)

Answer (score 0):

Normal subgroup of $S_3$ are $\{e\}$, $\{e, (123), (132)\}$, and $S_3$ itself.
All subgroups with two elements are not normal.

Comment: did you mean "subgroup with two elements"?

Comment: sorry for the mistake , you are correct. thank you for pointing