# Group and subgroup proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been trying to teach myself some group theory and have come a across that has really stumped me. It is as follows:

Prove that in any finite group $G$ with a subgroup $H$ of order exactly half that of $G$, the left
and right cosets of H in G are the same, i.e. for all $g ∈ G$ we have $gH = Hg$ and show that
this implies that $gHg^{-1}= H$.

Any help is very greatly appreciated.

Comment: In either case, one of the cosets is $H$.  What's the other?

Comment: @Randall What do you mean?

Comment: Think of the cosets by any $a \notin H$.

Comment: They both coincide with the complement of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $H\leq G$ and $[G:H]=2$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687227/if-h-leq-g-and-gh-2-then-h-is-normal-in-g)

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya No they are different questions

Comment: No, it is the same question.

Comment: @Randall How is it the same?

Comment: No! They are the same. You said that $\frac{o(G)}{o(H)}=2$ they wrote notationally $[G:H]=2$.

Comment: @YungNugget  In the finite case, $[G:H]=2$ is the same assumption as yours that $H$ is half the size of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g \in H$, then $Hg=H=gH$; if $g \notin H$, then necessarily both $Hg=\complement_GH$ and $gH=\complement_GH$, so $Hg=gH$. This is because the cosets have the same cardinality, so in your case they are just 2.

Now, $Hg=gH \Leftrightarrow (Hg \subseteq gH) \wedge (gH \subseteq Hg)$; $Hg \subseteq gH \Leftrightarrow \forall h \in H, \exists h' \in H \mid hg=gh' \Leftrightarrow \forall h \in H, \exists h' \in H \mid h=gh'g^{-1} \Leftrightarrow H \subseteq gHg^{-1}$, and likewise for the other term of the "$\wedge$", whence sets' equality.