# Groups without using Sylow

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, semidirect-product, automorphism-group

I am going over older papers that dont have solutions and again wanted to ask for some help. Previously in this exercise I proved the Recognition Criterion and the fact that if every element of $G$ has order at most 2, then $G$ is abelian and is isomorphic to $C_2$x$C_2$...x$C_2$ (n lots of $C_2$ for some n). I think I must somehow use this but I dont quite see how

Let G be a finite group such that $\vert G\vert = 2n$. Assume $G$ has a subgroup $K \subset G$ such that $\vert K \vert = n$. **WITHOUT USING SYLOWS THEOREMS** show the following:

i) $\exists q \in G$ such that $ord(q)=2$

ii) $K$ is normal and $G \cong K \rtimes_hQ $ for some homomorphism $h: Q \to Aut(K)$

I am really in a bind here. The case when the $n$ in $2n$ is prime was covered in our lectures but when $n$ is not prime, the situation obviously changes.

Comment: $K$ is normal because every subgroup of index 2 is normal.

Comment: Is $n$ odd? Otherwise ii) is not necessarily true. For example, a cyclic group of order $4$ is not isomorphic to a semidirect product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question $(i)$ follows from [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) for $p=2$. In question $(ii)$, if $K$ has index $2$, then it is normal:

[Subgroup of index 2 is Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal)