# Group with order $30$ is not a simple group.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Could someone prove the sentence given above in the title?

I know that Sylow theorems should be used here.

Let $N_{p}$ stands for number of $p$-Sylow subgroups in group $G$.

I tried to use following sentences:

- $\lvert G \rvert = 30 =2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$
- $N_{p} \equiv 1 \pmod p$
- $N_{p} \mid 30$

But i can't figure out.

Regards.

Comment: While it doesn't really impact your result in this case. One important thing to note is Sylow's theorem actually guarantees us that $N_p|30/p$. This reduces the number of cases you have to check, for example, 6 has 4 divisors, while 30 has 8.

Comment: You could also assume that there is more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup for each prime and count elements of order $p$ for each of the primes. This leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$If you know the result

> if the finite group $G$ has order $\Size{G} = 2 d$, with $d$ odd, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$,

then you are immediately in business.

Otherwise, check the possibilities for the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups, and consequently for the number of elements of order $5$. If $N_{5} > 1$, you will find that there won't be too many elements left.

Comment: As regards to the given result- I am not sure whether this going to help. A group is not simple when there exists non-trivial normal subgroup not just ordinary subgroup.

Comment: @mkultra Yes, but the result tells you that in a group $G$ of order $2d, d$ odd, you have a subgroup of order $d$, so $[G:H] = (2d)/d = 2$ and every subgroup of index $2$ is normal, you can see a proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal

Comment: I want to only ask for proof of the result mentioned by @Andreas Caranti.

Comment: @mkultra there is a [proof here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_is_twice_an_odd_number_implies_subgroup_of_index_two).