# Is Gabriel's Horn possible in four dimensions?

Tags: calculus, geometry, volume, infinity, paradoxes

[Gabriel's horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_horn), a shape with infinite surface area but finite volume, is one of the most counterintuitive objects in mathematics. However, it is pretty intuitive that we can build a [Gabriel's horn in two dimensions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y3h38084ly). It seems like it is "harder" to construct a Gabriel's horn in a higher number of dimensions. Is it even possible in four dimensions? If it is, what is the smallest dimension for which it is impossible, or is it possible for any number of dimensions?

Comment: The duplicate question itself is unclear.

Comment: Why is it unclear? The accepted answer is very clear.

Comment: Oops, the question itself isn't clear enough to satisfy what I wanted, but the accepted answer answers my question.

Comment: Is it possible for me to somehow get this closed as a duplicate now?

Comment: Isn't it good to keep duplicates?

Comment: I don't find it good. Some questions have been asked over and over again, and then the answers are not identical, but very similar. After a while the whole site gets overloaded with these "FAQ's". Of course, this question here is not as popular as the ones I mean (if you want an example: show that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal. Try to count how many times this has been asked and answered - start, say, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal))